# Could not find a part of the path, still not work

Tags: asp.net, path

I don't understand why my code does not work after i do with web.config

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<pages validateRequest="false">
```

then here is my code behind

```
if (fulAvatar_BT.HasFile)
            {
                int count = 1;
                string fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(fulAvatar_BT.PostedFile.FileName);
                string fullPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Resources/TinTucIMG/") + fileName1;

                string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);

                string newFullPath = fullPath;
                string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
                string fileName = "";

                while (File.Exists(newFullPath))
                {
                    string tempFileName = string.Format("{0}({1})", fileNameOnly, count++);
                    newFullPath = Path.Combine(path, tempFileName + extension);
                    fileName = tempFileName + extension;
                }

                fulAvatar_BT.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~/Resources/TinTucIMG/" + fileName));
                linkAnhBia = @"~/Resources/TinTucIMG/" + fileName;
            }

                fulAvatar_BT.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"/Resources/TinTucIMG/" + fileName)); //error here ???
                linkAnhBia = "~/Resources/TinTucIMG/" + fileName;
            }
```

when i use this function, it appears an error:

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'D:\Source\uptestsvn\AnPhuSchool\Resources\TinTucIMG\'.

you know, this path has existed, i've tested. I dont know why happened this error.

Comment: What exact line is throwing this error?

Comment: tks Rob Tillie, i have fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, i just fix my "fileName" by split newFullpath to the last part and i get fileName well.

```
string newFullPath = fullPath;
                string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
                //string fileName = "";

                while (File.Exists(newFullPath))
                {
                    string tempFileName = string.Format("{0}({1})", fileNameOnly, count++);
                    newFullPath = Path.Combine(path, tempFileName + extension);
                    //fileName = tempFileName + extension;
                }

                fulAvatar_BT.PostedFile.SaveAs(newFullPath);

                string[] mang = newFullPath.Split('/') ;
                string fileName = mang[mang.Length-1];
                linkAnhBia = @"~/Resources/TinTucIMG/" + fileName;
```